# Pandas Categorical masking

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have what I believe is a simple question but I can't find what I'm looking for in the docs.

I have a dataframe with a `Categorical` column called `mycol` with categories `a` and `b`  and would like to be mask a subset of the dataframe as follows:

`df_a = df[df.mycol.equal('a')]`

Currently I am doing:

```
df_a = df[df.mycol.cat.codes.values==df.mycol.cat.categories.to_list().index('a')]
```

which is obviously extremely verbose and inelegant. Since `df.mycol` has both the codes and the coded labels, it has all the information to perform this operation, so I'm wondering the best way to go about this...

Comment: `df_a = df[df.mycol == 'a']` does not work?

Comment: I can't understand what issue your current approach is supposed to be addressing

Comment: I test it with `df = pd.DataFrame({'mycol': pd.Categorical(list('aaabbbababab'))})` and `df_a = df[df.mycol == 'a']` working perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_a = df[df["mycol"]=='a']
```

I believe this should work, unless by 'mask' you mean you want to actually zero out the values that don't have a